# HtmlEditor - This is an invalid webresource WebResource.axd missing

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

In my asp.net webform application I have a problem with Ajax HTMLEditor control. On the content page, within the update panel, I have 3 HTMLEditor control.
When I open the page in Firefox, debbuger records error on line

```
/ / START HTMLEditor.DesignPanel.js
Type.registerNamespace ("Sys.Extended.UI.HTMLEditor") ...
/ / END HTMLEditor.DesignPanel.js
```

On the local computer this error does not create problems and application behave normally.
On a production server, this error makes real big problems. Occasionally during postback it throws the user session.
Elmah catches error: System.Web.HttpException: This is an invalid webresource request.

Relating to:
    /WebResource.axd?d=o2UO8Ba564lfuU5QBNIFonwI6LzaKfPl-6oTFth2MMUjED9lYqkPs29E7nw_eLFNKT63yrJ1Mxs3mO62IDGiyP3q5_pCSeLWItuaj2vnFb3IX00Y6PRxv6IXZaLwDC_7xo-iCwiDbmuwpnnnYFqDVWgvuiB5iz1jPYg3RkSXF6A1&t=635125941825518770

On the local computer Elmah not catch any errors of this type.

I found a link to
http://blogs.telerik.com/blogs/07-03-27/debugging-asp-net-2-0-web-resources-decrypting-the-url-and-getting-the-resource-name.aspx from where I downloaded WebResources.aspx page, which I copied to root of web app, on the production server, and then should be able to decrypt the above / WebResource.axd? D = o2UO .... in the name of the missing resource. But trying on a variety of different ways always get:
Error decrypting data. Are you running your page on the same server and inside the same application as the web resource URL that was generated?

Among other things, I found that there was an error with the latest version AjaxToolkit concerning Html.Editor and proposed to version - January 2013 release, which I took from http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/releases/view/100852
This reduced the frequency of errors and the application runs more stable, but still the problem is there.

The application is built on. NET 4.0 Framework.
I use ToolkitScriptManager
Within the content pages I registered control

```
<% @ Register Assembly = "Ajaxcontroltoolkit" Namespace = "AjaxControlToolkit.HTMLEditor" TagPrefix = "ajaxToolkit"%>
<% @ Register TagPrefix = "ajaxToolkit" Namespace = "Ajaxcontroltoolkit" Assembly = "Ajaxcontroltoolkit"%>
```

and in web.config

```
<controls>
  <add tagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" />
  <add assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit.HTMLEditor" tagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" />
</ Controls>
```

I'm running out of ideas what to do in order to fix it.

Do you have any suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this problem can be found at: http://forums.asp.net/p/1930532/5489055.aspx/1?p=True&t=635127832189897204